# Launch application with GUI from CGI script

Tags: windows-7, perl, cgi

Is it possible to launch application with GUI from CGI script (on Windows 7)?

---

Let's say that I want to launch [Video Lan (VLC)](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). How can I do it?

**1st attempt:**
I tried to use `exec` function in Perl. My CGI script `cgi-bin/Test.pl`:

```perl
#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

exec qq("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe");
```

**2nd attempt:**
My CGI script `cgi-bin/Test.pl`:

```perl
#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my @returnInfo = `C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Test.bat`;
print join("<br />", @returnInfo);
```

My `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test.bat`:

```
start "" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"
```

Unfortunately it does not work. `localhost:80/cgi-bin/Test.pl` is loading ~10 seconds and nothing appears.

When I start `Test.pl` and `Test.bat` manually window appears and everything works properly.

I expect that I should use `runas` command (as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/598816/launching-programs-remotely-via-ssh-on-windows-7)) but there is user's password prompt I can't fill automatically.

Comment: There is a `/savecred` option for `runas.exe` that saves the password.  So you could run the `runas.exe` command you need once, with this option, and then Windows should use the stored password the next time you invoke the command.

Comment: This option is unavailable for `Windows 7 Home` and `Windows 7 Starter Edition` (see documentation).

Comment: Maybe try setting a scheduled task (deactivated) and I think you might be able to trigger it with a `schtasks` command.